# How to install hda-jack-retask in 14.04?

Tags: sound, 14.04, hda-intel

I recently upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04. My HP has Beats (cue groans of pain, as it's just a gimmick).

In 12.04, I used [hda-jack-retask](https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda) to fix it. However, as far as I can tell he has not updated it to work with 14.04. Is there a different tool out there to get Beats to work with Linux?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please have a look at:

### PPA description

> [...]
>
> Note: as of Ubuntu 13.10, **hda-jack-retask is part of alsa-tools.**
>
> Just install the `alsa-tools-gui` package from the regular archive and start `hdajackretask`.
>
> [...]

<sup>Source: [HD audio related stuff](https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda)</sup>

So simply open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```