# ubuntu 15.04 no sound

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa

there is no sound on my desktop and my Chassis Information are:

```
Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
```

And

```
☁ $  sudo dmidecode                             
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
76 structures occupying 3104 bytes.
Table at 0x000EC070.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: F1
    Release Date: 02/24/2015
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 4096 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: B85M-D2V-TM
    Version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    UUID: 038D0240-045C-0525-2F06-180700080009
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Family: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: B85M-D2V-TM
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L1
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Maximum Size: 256 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Other
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L2
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 1024 kB
    Maximum Size: 1024 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L3
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 6144 kB
    Maximum Size: 6144 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Centronics Type-14
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2A
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2B
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Video
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB3
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9A1 - TPM HDR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9C1 - PCIE DOCKING CONN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2B3 - CPU FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6C2 - EXT HDMI
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3C1 - GMCH FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1D1 - ITP
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E2 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E4 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E3 - LPC HOT DOCKING
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E1 - SCAN MATRIX
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G1 - LPC SIDE BAND
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8F1 - UNIFIED
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6F1 - LVDS
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2F1 - LAI FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2G1 - GFX VID
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1G6 - AC JACK
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B2
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 0
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.0

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6D1
    Type: x8 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:01.0

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J7B1
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:03.0

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8B4
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.7

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8B3
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 6
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:14:1e.0

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    String 2: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    String 3: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    String 4: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    String 5: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
    Power-On Password Status: Disabled
    Keyboard Password Status: Disabled
    Administrator Password Status: Disabled
    Front Panel Reset Status: Disabled

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 34, 11 bytes
Management Device
    Description: LM78-1
    Type: LM78
    Address: 0x00000000
    Address Type: I/O Port

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 26, 22 bytes
Voltage Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Status: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Management Device Handle: 0x002B
    Component Handle: 0x002B
    Threshold Handle: 0x002C

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 28, 22 bytes
Temperature Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Status: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Management Device Handle: 0x002B
    Component Handle: 0x002E
    Threshold Handle: 0x002F

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x002F
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Status: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Cooling Dev 1

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Management Device Handle: 0x002B
    Component Handle: 0x0031
    Threshold Handle: 0x0032

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x002F
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Status: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Not Specified

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Management Device Handle: 0x002B
    Component Handle: 0x0034
    Threshold Handle: 0x0035

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 29, 22 bytes
Electrical Current Probe
    Description: ABC
    Location: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Status: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Management Device Handle: 0x002B
    Component Handle: 0x0037
    Threshold Handle: 0x0035

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 26, 22 bytes
Voltage Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 28, 22 bytes
Temperature Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x003C
    Type: Power Supply Fan
    Status: OK
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Cooling Dev 1

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 29, 22 bytes
Electrical Current Probe
    Description: ABC
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x003F, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
System Power Supply
    Power Unit Group: 1
    Location: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Model Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Revision: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Max Power Capacity: Unknown
    Status: Present, OK
    Type: Switching
    Input Voltage Range Switching: Auto-switch
    Plugged: Yes
    Hot Replaceable: No
    Input Voltage Probe Handle: 0x003B
    Cooling Device Handle: 0x003D
    Input Current Probe Handle: 0x003E

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard LAN
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:19.0

Handle 0x0041, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: SOCKET 0
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i7
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: C3 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 60, Stepping 3
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
    Voltage: 1.0 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 7000 MHz
    Current Speed: 3500 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0004
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Fill By OEM
    Part Number: Fill By OEM
    Core Count: 4
    Core Enabled: 1
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0042, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0044, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: 0420
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F3-1600C11-8GNT   
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0044
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0047
    Partition Row Position: Unknown
    Interleave Position: Unknown
    Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0007
    Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x004D, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        88 06 4D 00 00 00

Handle 0x004E, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        83 40 4E 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        F8 00 50 8C 00 00 00 00 01 20 00 00 00 00 09 00
        CA 05 1E 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 66 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00

Handle 0x004F, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 7
        en|US|iso8859-1
        de|DE|iso8859-1
        ru|RU|iso8859-5
        ko|KR|unicode
        ja|JP|unicode
        zh|CS|unicode
        zh|CT|unicode
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x0055, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Information on audio:

```
☁  $  lspci| grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)

☁  $  cat /proc/asound/cards 
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7210000 irq 30
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17

☁ $  aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My problem is there is no sound on the front Chassis Phone Out, but has sound on the back of the Chassis. And I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Try running alsamixer in a terminal and see if there is an output that is muted. Also, are you sure it's physically wired correctly?

Comment: @o9000, the physically wired is no problem, and all the desktops in my office occured the same problem.

Comment: OK. If you can't get anywhere with alsamixer, you might have some luck with hda-jack-retask which can reroute sound pins on some cards. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/456579/how-to-install-hda-jack-retask-in-14-04 and http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/

Comment: @o9000, thanks, with alsamixer, the problem has been solved. And you should answer the problem so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what can be tried in a situation like this:

- Running alsamixer in a terminal and see if there is an output that is muted;
- Checking if the jack is wired correctly to the sound card;
- Fiddling with hda-jack-retask, which can reroute sound pins on some cards. If this ends up the solution, maybe a bug should be reported in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

(summarized from my comments above)